# My image can't be loaded into my ImageView. What went wrong?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

I'm trying to load a specific image from my directory into the ImageView on my app, but it's not working. The whole thing became blank. Can someone please take a look and see where my code went wrong? Thanks!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_viewer);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    try {
       //this toast below appears
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "try",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

       //below is the path for the image
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://sdcard/myFoodDiary/snaps/default.jpg");

        System.out.println("Image URI: " + uri.toString());
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oops", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Put the image elsewhere -- somewhere you've accessed successfully before -- and see if it works. Whichever outcome -- if it does or doesn't work -- you'll glean some information.

Comment: did you add the permission to read SDCard?

Comment: @Obversity, it should work, although I've never tried accessing it elsewhere.

Comment: @HamidShatu, yes, permission already already in the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not a valid path:

```
Uri.parse("file://sdcard/myFoodDiary/snaps/default.jpg");
```

Try

```
Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFoodDiary/snaps/default.jpg");
```

But I'd better do something like

```
File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFoodDiary/snaps/default.jpg");
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Comment: missed a "/" in front of myFoodDiary, but otherwise awesome! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, correct codes as Artoo Detoo states:

```
File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFoodDiary/snaps/default.jpg");
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```